# Discord JS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to use multiple user mentions and `message.mention.members.first()` cannot do this. So I did some digging and found this function from [Parsing Mention Arguments](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work):

```
function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;

    if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }

        return client.users.cache.get(mention);
    }
}
```

When I try to use this function I get the "Discord JS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined" here is the code causing the error

```
            let channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === args[0]);
            const user1 = getUserFromMention(args[1]);
            const user2 = getUserFromMention(args[2]);
            message.member.voice.setChannel(channel.id);
            user1.voice.setChannel(channel.id);
            user2.voice.setChannel(channel.id);
```

This code Is meant to move Myself and mentioned users to selected Voice Channel it works perfectly fine when using `message.mention.members.first()` but can only handle one out of two of the mentioned users.

I was wondering if there was a fix for my current error or if there is another way I should be working this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that,

`message.mentions.members`- Returns a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) whereas
`client.users.cache.get` - Returns a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

You can only move/disconnect [GuildMembers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) across VCs.

Therefore you can use `message.mentions.members`, which returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of all mentioned Users.

```js
let channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === args[0]);
message.member.voice.setChannel(channel.id);
message.mentions.members.each(u => {
    u.voice.setChannel(channel.id);
})
```

Comment: Ah, alright learn something new everyday thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be, that the user is not in cache, so you must use [GuildMemberManager#fetch(id)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch). Problem is, that this function is async. The easiest solution is to make getUserFromMention and the functions where you use it async and use await.